# Sum of list of object fields using stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a object

```
Class DummyObject() {
    double first;
    double second;
    double third;
    double fourth;
}

Class SomeObject() {
    List<DummyObject> objectList;
}

Class HighestObject() {
    List<SomeObject> objectList;
}
```

A variable of type SomeObject is given. I have to find out if sum of four field in DummyObject is not getting equal to amount X.

using for loop, It can easily be written like:

```
for(SomeObject someObject : hightestObject.getObjectList()) {
    for(DummyObject dummyObject : someObject.getObjectList()){
        if((dummyObject.first + dummyObject.second + dummyObject.third + dummyObject.fourth) != X) {
             return false;
        }
    }
}
```

How can we do it using java stream ?

Comment: I think you have a mistake in the code in this if you add dummyObject.first + dummyObject.first + dummyObject.first + dummyObject.first - it's the same field 4 times

Comment: yeah my bad.. updated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could combine `flatMap` and `anyMatch`:

```
HighestObject h = ...;

boolean foundNotX = h.getObjectList().stream() //Stream<SomeObject>
                  .flatMap(so -> so.getObjectList().stream()) //Stream<DummyObject>
                  .mapToDouble(o -> o.first + o.second + o.third + o.fourth) //DoubleStream
                  .anyMatch(sum -> sum != X);
if (foundNotX) return false;
```

Depending on what you are after, using `.allMatch(sum -> sum == X)` might be more appropriate.

Comment: Do allMatch with == instead of != and just return directly

Comment: @Michael That wouldn't be equivalent to the original code, which only returns if not all match, hence the extra boolean variable. Of course, if the next line, which hasn't been shown, is `return true;` then your comment would apply, which is why I put a note at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: @assylias original code returns false if any of the sum doesn't matches.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
return hightestObject.getObjectList().stream()
    .flatMap(someObject -> someObject.getObjectList().stream())
    .allMatch(dummyObject ->
        dummyObject.first + dummyObject.second + dummyObject.third + dummyObject.fourth == X);
```